# Is it possible using css to have 2nd line flush right?

Tags: jquery, css

I am styling a css menu in a vertical column.  Where a menu item doesn't fit, I would like the over run to be flush right.

```
|                    |
| o Item             |
| o Item             |
| o Longer link that |
|         doesn't fit|
|                    |
```

I tried doing this with the pseudo selector first-line:

```
<style>
p {
   text-align:right;
   background-color:pink;
   }

p:first-line
   {
   text-align:left;
   background-color:yellow;
   }
</style>
```

but the first-line new value for text-align is ignored, while the background color is accepted.

A:  Is this possible in CSS?
B:  If not, can you suggest a simple non-CSS work around?

Comment: `text-align` is not within the properties that can be used with [`::first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line).

Answer (score 0):

The `text-align` property can't use with the `:first-line` pseudo selector

**The allowed properties are,**

1. font properties
2. color property
3. background properties
4. ‘word-spacing’
5. ‘letter-spacing’
6. ‘text-decoration’
7. ‘vertical-align’
8. ‘text-transform’
   9.‘line-height’

Check it on [**here**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Selectors/pseudo-elements/%3afirst-line)

The better way is to wrap the text using a `span` tag and then apply the style.